# view not creating

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

Trying to write a view in oracle 11g 
 
I want this code to return just the fist name and the last name of a employee who has . 

 But it keeps on giving me the error : "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression"

```
create or replace view highesttotalcommission as (
    select *
    from  (     select e.firstname|| ' ' ||e.lastname "Highest commission"
            from employee e
            inner join salesperson sp
            on e.employeeID = sp.employeeID
            inner join salesinvoice si
            on si.salespersonid = e.employeeID
            group by si.salespersonid
            order by SUM(si.price * sp.commissionpct) desc )
    where ROWNUM = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is pretty obvious.  You need to include the columns or expression in the `select` in the `group by`:

```
create or replace view highesttotalcommission as
    select *
    from  (select (e.firstname || ' ' || e.lastname) as "Highest commission"
           from employee e inner join
                salesperson sp
                on e.employeeID = sp.employeeID inner join
                salesinvoice si
                on si.salespersonid = e.employeeID
            group by si.salespersonid, e.firstname|| ' ' ||e.lastname
            order by SUM(si.price * sp.commissionpct) desc
          ) e
    where ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: but why look even when I edit the code to something which you should be able to group by  it still returns that error

Comment: @NedCharles . . . The query in this answer should not be generating that particular error